# JSON to C# Class different key

Tags: c#, json

```
{  
   "subscriptionId":"d56accdf-47eb-405c-b8fa-3b6577a52992",
   "objectId":"17d936e3-f96c-4752-8cdc-ffa9b3437ee9",
   "objectType":"Group",
   "eventType":"ActionResponse",
   "eventId":"e2641057-1cc8-42f2-83ad-aae75b32ff1d",
   "data":{  
      "actionId":"c0414e3f-44a8-4377-afe5-6047ba367b3c",
      "actionPackageId":"com.microsoft.kaizala.miniapps.attendanceCard.GA",
      "packageId":"com.microsoft.kaizala.miniapps.attendanceCard.GA",
      "groupId":"17d936e3-f96c-4752-8cdc-ffa9b3437ee9",
      "sourceGroupId":"17d936e3-f96c-4752-8cdc-ffa9b3437ee9",
      "responseId":"e2641057-1cc8-42f2-83ad-aae75b32ff1d",
      "isUpdateResponse":false,
      "responder":"+919998902575",
      "responderId":"dd1df3da-64bd-4c4c-b18f-99c9279da1f2",
      "creatorId":"dd1df3da-64bd-4c4c-b18f-99c9279da1f2",
      "responderName":"Piyush Kanpariya",
      "responderProfilePic":"https://cdn.inc-000.kms.osi.office.net/usr/7318c832e091260306a2a10b99edb225a35efd8ba2ba0c0383017911f06923f8.jpg",
      "isAnonymous":false,
      "responseDetails":{  
         "responseWithQuestions":[  
            {  
               "title":"You can respond to this survey multiple times. To remember each response, you can give it any name or leave it as-is below.",
               "type":"Text",
               "options":[  
               ],
               "answer":"Response 1"
            },
            {  
               "title":"Responder Location",
               "type":"Location",
               "options":[      
               ],
               "answer":{  
                  "lt":23.0509208,
                  "lg":72.4897822,
                  "n":"14, Thaltej Rd, Thaltej, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380058, India",
                  "acc":31.843000411987305
               }
            },
            {  
               "isInvisible":true,
               "title":"ResponseTime",
               "type":"DateTime",
               "options":[  

               ],
               "answer":1546246937008
            },
            {  
               "title":"PhotoQuestionTitle",
               "type":"Image",
               "options":[  

               ],
               "answer":"https://cdn.inc-000.kms.osi.office.net/att/80461cf6ceb4e206664d0c88488d2c0618ce1d5147c215b0ebef6593aaa32554.jpg?sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=5VfNHctjVTh0RenZjhRtGP%2Byu5cBNwuUFINPB4pMekU%3D&st=2018-12-31T08:02:18Z&se=2292-10-15T09:02:18Z&sp=r"
            },
            {  
               "title":"NotesQuestionTitle",
               "type":"Text",
               "options":[  

               ],
               "answer":"Goooo"
            }
         ]
      },
      "Properties":[  
         {  
            "n":"DateTime",
            "t":1,
            "v":"2"
         },
         {  
            "n":"locationOrPhotoSettingText",
            "v":"With Photo and Location"
         },
         {  
            "n":"locationOrPhotoSettingIcon",
            "v":"photoWithLocationIcon.png"
         },
         {  
            "n":"expiryDateProperty",
        "v":"Till Mon, 31 Dec, 23:59"
         }
      ]
   },
   "context":"Any data which is required to be returned in callback. Current webhook data can be seen by refreshing: https://requestb.in/12786un1?inspect",
   "fromUser":"+91XXXXXXXXXX",
   "fromUserId":"dd1df3da-64bd-4c4c-b18f-99c9279da1f2",
   "isBotfromUser":false,
   "fromUserName":"XYZ",
   "fromUserProfilePic":"https://cdn.inc-000.kms.osi.office.net/usr/7318c832e091260306a2a10b99edb225a35efd8ba2ba0c0383017911f06923f8.jpg"
}
```

Comment: There is no question here, can you perhaps specifically explain what you want, or whats not working

Comment: What is exactly the question ?

Comment: What is your question? Could you please share what you need with us?

Comment: This is a valid JSON. You can use the Visual Studio `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes` tool to convert this object to C# classes, if that is the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class ResponseWithQuestion
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<object> options { get; set; }
    public object answer { get; set; }
    public bool? isInvisible { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseDetails
{
    public List<ResponseWithQuestion> responseWithQuestions { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public string n { get; set; }
    public int t { get; set; }
    public string v { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string actionId { get; set; }
    public string actionPackageId { get; set; }
    public string packageId { get; set; }
    public string groupId { get; set; }
    public string sourceGroupId { get; set; }
    public string responseId { get; set; }
    public bool isUpdateResponse { get; set; }
    public string responder { get; set; }
    public string responderId { get; set; }
    public string creatorId { get; set; }
    public string responderName { get; set; }
    public string responderProfilePic { get; set; }
    public bool isAnonymous { get; set; }
    public ResponseDetails responseDetails { get; set; }
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string subscriptionId { get; set; }
    public string objectId { get; set; }
    public string objectType { get; set; }
    public string eventType { get; set; }
    public string eventId { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public string context { get; set; }
    public string fromUser { get; set; }
    public string fromUserId { get; set; }
    public bool isBotfromUser { get; set; }
    public string fromUserName { get; set; }
    public string fromUserProfilePic { get; set; }
}
```

try convert `answer` property to intended type by TryParse Method

Answer (score 0):

I use this static method to get property values from json and set into my class object:
(add Newtonsoft.Json)

```
public static string GetValObj(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    if (obj is JContainer container)
    {
        var nsj = container.First;
        do
        {
            if (string.Equals(nsj.Path, propertyName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                if (((JValue)((JProperty)nsj).Value).Value == null)
                    return string.Empty;
                return ((JValue)((JProperty)nsj).Value).Value
                    .ToString();
            }

            nsj = nsj.Next;
        } while (nsj != null);
    }

    return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
}
```